# How to configure the django forms to sell custom products?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms

I have just started learning Django and have a simple shopping cart setup following the tutorial by Antonio Mele in his book "Django 2 by Example". I can select products and then the quantity will be an option. This works fine for generic products. What if I have custom products such as engraved pens? The buyer selects quantity of 3 but he wants different names engraved on the pens. How would I do that?

Here is the code for the forms.py that controls the quantity.

```
from django import forms

PRODUCT_QUANTITY_CHOICES = [(i, str(i)) for i in range(1, 11)]

class CartAddProductForm(forms.Form):
    quantity = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=PRODUCT_QUANTITY_CHOICES, coerce=int)
    update = forms.BooleanField(required=False, initial=False, widget=forms.HiddenInput)
```

and the relevant part of the HTML template looks like

```
  {% for item in cart %}
    {% with product=item.product %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
        <td>
          <form action="{% url "cart:cart_add" product.id %}" method="post">
            {{ item.update_quantity_form.quantity }}
            {{ item.update_quantity_form.update }}
            <input type="submit" value="Update">
            {% csrf_token %}
          </form>
        </td>
        <td><a href="{% url "cart:cart_remove" product.id %}">Remove</a></td>
        <td class="num">${{ item.price }}</td>
        <td class="num">${{ item.total_price }}</td>
      </tr>
    {% endwith %}
  {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

great you started with Django.

For complex shop systems, there is already a lot of work done for you in the background if you decide to use a pre-built Django package.

You find all good and well-maintained ecommerce packages here: https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/ecommerce/

A very good starting point would be to read the documentation of django-oscar, which is the best up-to-date ecommerce shop system. Like this, you can really dive into all the opportunities with django shops and use a reliable system in the background.

If you'd like to stick to your tutorial though, you may do it like this:

1. Add text field to your Pen model like `engrave_text = models.CharField(default=None)`
2. Add engrave_text as form field for a form like AddEngravedPenToCartForm.

Like this, each individually engraved pen is an individual product of its own.

Kind regards,
Ben

Comment: Does Django Oscar have a lot of dependencies that I need to install? It's really painful trying to debug what is going wrong when there are lots of moving parts. I am torn between using a major solution like Django Oscar or starting from scratch. I am just worried if I hit a roadblock in Django Oscar, the stuff I learn is not transferable.

Comment: Well, don't be afraid, just try. Just do: 1. "manage.py mkvirtualenv oscar" 2. "pip install django-oscar" (will install a brand new blank version of django just for testing) 3. django-admin.py startproject demo_shop. Like this you can test all functionality without breaking anything. And read the docs: https://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/releases-1.1/internals/getting_started.html